# Django Channels vs Socket.io for online card game

Tags: websocket, socket.io, django-channels

I want to develop a django app where few players connect to a room and then they can play different card games, for example poker. I decided to use websockets or something like this. So my options are django channels in server and websockets in client or socket.io in client and socket.io implementation for python.

I was looking for some comparison between them but most of the posts are pretty old. So what are the benefits and downsides of both?